# Issue with Installing Damn Vulnerable Linux (DVL)

Tags: linux, boot

I just came across this Linux distribution Damn Vulnerable Linux and downloaded the ISO file.i tried  to run it directly with ISO image in VirtualBox.

But it message like

```
ioslinux 3.36 2007-02-10 copyright 1994-2007 h peter anvin isolinux:
boot:
```

(which I think points to non bootable media) and asking for kernel image.
I mounted the iso file, then tried few files like vmlinuz in mounted directory but VM unable to find them and display another message

> unable to find kernel image

Then I tried to burn image to  DVD with NERO(bootable options). This time I am not getting any message at boot time. Just a blinking cursor for ever.

How to make a live DVD out of that iso?

Comment: First of all, I think you should ask this question at `superuser`. Anyway check the downloaded file checksum. maybe it's corrupted. If it boots up on virtualbox, then it should boot when it's burned to a DVD. just for sure try other apps than `Nero` (ie. `CloneCD`).

Comment: Maybe its already hacked? That is damn vulnerable. ;-)

Comment: its interesting little distro, though by its very nature, not *quite* up to date ;p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, I feel really silly actually saying this out loud.  When it gets to the boot: prompt.....just press enter

it will boot.

as far as burning the ISO, don't mess with boot options.  just burn the iso like a normal data disk.

Comment: Thanks !! sometimes the most simple things are hardest to think of...silly me!!  and thanks for that ISO boot option advice :)